# Uploading Excel file to server, encoding question

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to upload a file with Ant Design Upload (https://ant.design/components/upload/) to a lambda function, when it arrives a console.log shows something like:

> -----------------------------130470879520252100791020369308   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";
>   filename="Ao6kyE7YF5KUaKFm.xlsx"   Content-Type:
>   application/wps-office.xlsx
>
> PK[M...

I have no clue what type of format it is. Is it binary? And how can i save it as a file?. I tried using this without success. It creates the file with the literal string from above.

```
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.xlsx", event.body, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the extension of the file from .xlsx to .zip you can see that it's a zipped archive. All office extensions ending in 'x' have the same behavior (.docx, .pptx, etc). For dealing with Excel files I'd recommend [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) for reading and writing Excel files. If you need something particular to Node they have a demo [here](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/tree/master/demos/server).

Also the reason it shows up that way as a string is because of data compression. As an interesting side note, the reason it starts off with PK is because the inventors of the zip format were [PKWare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKWare).